# Siemens Part Number(s)

Tags: sensor

Hy guys, anyone with an information based on Part number(s) for SIEMENS QRB1 Photo Resistive Flame Detectors? 
I have also attached the image of the detector I am referring to.

[image]

Comment: [What information do you need that isn't in the readily available datasheet?](http://www.techrite.com.au/pdfs/Techrite-Siemens-siemens-Qrb1-qrb3-Flame-Detector-013060323805.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

From the amazon site where the picture came from, we get a part number of B01BORY2F6, which does not make sense from [Siemens datasheet](http://www.techrite.com.au/pdfs/Techrite-Siemens-siemens-Qrb1-qrb3-Flame-Detector-013060323805.pdf).

No plug or flange, so by a process of elimination, we get eight possibilities:

[image]

[image]

g = Casing length - majority left - 50mm - 5cm.

l = Cable length - variable

m = Stripped length - variable

So stripped length appears to be less than casing length, so 70mm can be excluded (in green).  6 left.

It has a ferrule, so the version without ferrule can be left off (in purple).  5 left.

Assuming 4cm stripped length or 5cm casing, rough length is 30cm.

From amazon site: Product Dimensions    50 x 1.5 x 1.5 cm

Dimensions: 5cm casing + 35cm length + 4cm stripped = 44cm

So actual Siemens part number should be: **QRB1B-A035B40A** with 5 cm casing

Alternative: **QRB1B-B035B40A** with 6.5 cm casing.

You should be able to figure it out from your actual dimensions from this.